# Using entity reference, need to get the nodes path in templates

Tags: nodes, entities

I have two content types. Projects and People. I installed entity reference which has allowed me to create a field in projects that consists of a drop down of all the nodes in People. Great! So then I printed out the value from the projects field in the projects node template, even better! What I would love to do is get the people node url path in the project template so people can click through from the project and get the profile for the person the project belongs to, is this possible (in the node template for project)?

Comment: This sounds like you are using some bad practices. You should not have to add a field value to your node.tpl.php after adding it to the content type if the tpl is written correctly. The function you are looking for is [user_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load/7). This should be added in a preprocess hook or something to keep your tpl clean.

Comment: People is a content type, I want to crate a link to the node that's added to the project node. People are not drupal users. There just a list of staff.

Comment: think I got it, $foo[0]["entity"]->nid gets me the ID and that's mostly what I need anyway!

Comment: If you were using the entity reference field correctly. Through a view or rendering it naturally through a normal tpl you would be able to choose to render the output as a link to the associated content.

Comment: ah ok, how do I do it correctly? I jsut selected the content type in bundles?

Comment: After you have added the field to your content type click on 'Manage display' or navigate to `admin/structure/types/manage/your-content-type/display`. Click on the cog for the format column and click on the checkbox to display the field as a link.